# XML parser cannot detect tag

Tags: ios, iphone, xml, nsxmlparser

Im am using the SMXMLDocument (https://github.com/nfarina/xmldocument) to parse an xml document. All the other tags like title and date work fine. Except this tag called `jwplayer:hd.file`. The array returns a Null object.

```
 <item>
    <id>
        7994
    </id>
    <title>
        title goes here
    </title>
    <link>
        http://xml.xml
    </link>
    <guid>
        xml.xml
    </guid>
    <description>
        description goes here
    </description>
    <pubDate>
        19/11/2010
    </pubDate>
    <enclosure url="mp3" type="audio/mpeg" length="4604084"></enclosure>
    <guid isPermaLink="true">
                  mp3
    </guid>
    <media:credit role="author">
       mediacredit
    </media:credit>
    <media:content expression="full" medium="audio" duration="2297"  url="mp3" fileSize="4604084"></media:content>
    <jwplayer:hd.file>
        http://mp3
    </jwplayer:hd.file>
    <media:thumbnail url="jpg"></media:thumbnail>
    <itunes:subtitle>
    sutitle goes here
    </itunes:subtitle>
    <itunes:duration>
        00:38:17
    </itunes:duration>
    <itunes:author>
    author
    </itunes:author>
</item>
<item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem once. It seems like the Tagscanner stops at the ".". 
Setting "jwplayer:hd" as tag should do the trick.